# asp.net mvc4 call ajax recursively

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, recursion

I need to call an action that returns me a model with a list and a flag telling me whether the  query has loaded completely or not, if this flag is false, I must call the action again and append these new results to the previous, and so on, until the flag is true. my ajax call is something like this:

```
function load() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "/MyController/Action",
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            traditional: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ...params....
            }),
            type: "POST",
            success: function (d) {
               $("#mydiv").html(d);
            },
            complete: function () {
               setTimeout(load, 2000);
            }
        });
     }
```

How can I check this flag (which comes as part of the model from the action)????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.10+ then you can use the resposeJSON property of the jqXHR object like

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/MyController/Action",
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({...params....
        }),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (d) {
            $("#mydiv").html(d);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR) {
            if (!jqXHR.responseJSON || !jqXHR.responseJSON.flag) {
                setTimeout(load, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

if not you need to handler the success and failure handlers

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/MyController/Action",
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        traditional: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({...params....
        }),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (d) {
            $("#mydiv").html(d);
            if (!d.flag) {
                setTimeout(load, 2000);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            setTimeout(load, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in my ajax d.flag isn't valid, because the action returns a PartialView, so the content of d is an html... any idea?

Comment: Finally I merge your solution and the one here: http://www.symatix.co.uk/articles/mvc/how-to-render-html-return-json-response and solved my problem, so I will mark your answer as accepted, thank you.